# Loading shapefiles from cloud storage bucket into Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I understand how to load images from my cloud storage buckets into GEE. I do this with ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF. I also wish to load data from various shapefiles that I keep in my storage buckets. I know that I can load this as 'assets' into my GEE account, and then 'import' them from there. However, I am looking for an option that does not require this step, and that allows me to pull all data from GCS.

Answer (score 0):

Earth Engine only supports the shapefile format for uploading into an asset, not for direct use during a computation. You can [use the command line tool to create an asset using data copied from Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line#upload), but you cannot skip the asset creation.